Add custom class to child aura component
I have to modify an aura component. I've never worked with aura components so I'm lost here.
Basically we have a parent aura component, which iterates child components:
<tbody >
    <aura:iteration items="{!v.filas}" var="fila">
        <c:ventasDistribuidorRow fila="{!fila}" />
    </aura:iteration>
</tbody>

The child component renders a table row element with inner table cells. I just want to add a css class to the tr:
<tr class="{!v.fila.cssClass}">

The css classes are defined in the child component css file:
.THIS {
}

.THIS .sembra-evolucion{
    background-color: green;
}

.THIS .variedad-normal{
    background-color: white;
}

This doesn't work. When I inspect the rendered tr elements, I can see that a class is already set, with the name of the aura component:

What is the correct way to add css classes to my child component?

Are the styles you're trying to apply in the parent or child component? What does the aura:attribute of fila look like in the child component? Any other relevant details that may be helpful would be appreciated.

@sfdcfox I edited the post to show how the css is defined, in the child component's css file.
